# Exception Using PayPal-PHP-SDK [Http response code 400]

Tags: php, pdo, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm following a tutorial about how to use PayPal-PHP-SDK and i got stuck in somewhere with this error in the console:

```
[Sun Mar 08 16:11:21.729977 2015] [:error] [pid 4484:tid 1760] [client ::1:4308] PHP Fatal error:  
Uncaught exception 'PayPal\\Exception\\PayPalConnectionException' with message 
'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' 
in C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Core\\PayPalHttpConnection.php:176\nStack trace:\n#0 
C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Transport\\PayPalRestCall.php(74): 
PayPal\\Core\\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...')\n#1 
C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Common\\PayPalResourceModel.php(103): 
PayPal\\Transport\\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL)\n#2 
C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Api\\Payment.php(424): 
PayPal\\Common\\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\\Rest\\ApiContext), NULL)\n#3 
C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\member\\payment.php(48): PayPal\\Api\\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\\Rest\\ApiContext))\n#4 {mai in 
C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Core\\PayPalHttpConnection.php on line 176, referer: http://localhost:1313/PayPal/
```

UPDATE

The new message from the log after try updating the name of the function is:

```
[Mon Mar 09 23:28:26.612147 2015] [:error] [pid 4344:tid 1772] [client ::1:2189] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PayPal\\Exception\\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Core\\PayPalHttpConnection.php:176\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Transport\\PayPalRestCall.php(74): PayPal\\Core\\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...')\n#1 C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Common\\PayPalResourceModel.php(103): PayPal\\Transport\\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL)\n#2 C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Api\\Payment.php(424): PayPal\\Common\\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\\Rest\\ApiContext), NULL)\n#3 C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\member\\payment.php(48): PayPal\\Api\\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\\Rest\\ApiContext))\n#4 {mai in C:\\UniServerZ\\www\\PayPal\\vendor\\paypal\\rest-api-sdk-php\\lib\\PayPal\\Core\\PayPalHttpConnection.php on line 176, referer: http://localhost:1313/PayPal/
```

This is the code:

```
<?php

use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;

require '../scr/start.php';

$payer = new Payer();
$details = new Details();
$amount = new Amount();
$transaction = new Transaction();
$payment = new Payment();
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();

// Payer
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

// Details
$details->setShipping('2.00')
    ->setTax('0.00')
    ->setSubtotal('20.00'); //feed for membership

// Amount
$amount->setCurrency('CLP')
    ->setTotal('22.00') // Shipping + Tax + Subtotal + Everything else you need to charge
    ->setDetails($details);

// Transaction
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setDescription('Membership');

$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setTransactions([$transaction]);

// Redirect URLs
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://localhost:1313/PayPal/PayPall/Pay.php?approved=true')
    ->setCancelUrl('http://localhost:1313/PayPal/PayPall/Pay.php?approved=false');

$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

try {

    $payment->create($api);

    // Generate and store hash
    // Prepare and execute transaction storage



} catch (PPConnectionException $e) {
    // Perhaps log an error
    header('Location: ../PayPall/error.php');

}

var_dump($payment->getLinks());

?>
```

Any orientation, question for improve this same question, comment, advice or request of clarification/more info about it, etc[...] than help to reach the solution of the problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: This sort of thing is the reason I developed my own [PHP class library for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) years ago, and myself and many others (including PayPal integration reps) prefer it over the PayPal SDK.  I'd take a look.  You could be up and running within minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this code change. `PPConnectionException` was renamed to `PayPalConnectionException`. You could also do `$e->getData()` to retrieve detailed exception message.

```
} catch (PayPalConnectionException $e) {
    echo $e->getData();
    // Perhaps log an error
    header('Location: ../PayPall/error.php');

}
```

Comment: Can you please point us to the tutorial that you are following. We can make the fix there too, to remove any future issues.

Comment: sure, is in this specifical video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Puxyk7cKvY but still have the error, your answer doesn't fix it
Any other idea?, thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure you are also updating the `use` statement too. As in `PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException`

Comment: it actually works for me also, thanks a lot, been battling this for hours, as Jaypatel said remmber to use   use PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException