# Paypal PHP SDK HTTP Error during a transaction update

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, paypal-rest-sdk

I am developing a ecommerce site for a friend and in the process of updating Paypal with the shipping amount prior to executing the payment, and I get the following error. This error is occuring when I call on Patch, PatchRequest, and then try executing the payment. Here is all of the code:

```
if (Input::get('action', 'get') === "getDetails") { //Check to see if the action parameter is set to getDetails

      $payment = \PayPal\Api\Payment::get(Input::get('paymentId', 'get'), $paypalAPI);

      $payerInfo = $payment->getPayer()->payer_info;
      if (!empty($payment)){
        $quantity = 0;
        foreach ($payment->transactions[0]->item_list->items as $item) {
          $quantity += $item->quantity;
        }
        if ($quantity <= 20) {
          $parcelType = "MediumFlatRateBox";
        } else if ($quantity > 20) {
          $parcelType = "LargeFlatRateBox";
        }
        $shipment = \EasyPost\Shipment::create([
          'from_address' => \EasyPost\Address::retrieve(Config::get('easypost/addressObjectID')),
          'to_address' => [
            'name' => $payerInfo->shipping_address->recipient_name,
            'street1'=> $payerInfo->shipping_address->line1,
            'street2' => (isset($payerInfo->shipping_address->line2)) ? $payerInfo->shipping_address->line2 : null,
            'city' =>$payerInfo->shipping_address->city,
            'state' => $payerInfo->shipping_address->state,
            'country' => $payerInfo->shipping_address->country_code,
            'zip' => $payerInfo->shipping_address->postal_code,
            'email' => $payerInfo->email
          ],
          'parcel' => [
            'predefined_package' => $parcelType,
            'weight' => 520
          ]
        ]);
        //Grab the lowest shipping rate
        $shippingRate = $shipment->lowest_rate()->rate;
        //Make a call to PayPal updating our transaction with the tax and shipping rate
        $amount = $payment->transactions[0]->amount;
        $transactionUpdate = new \PayPal\Api\Patch();
        $transactionUpdate    ->setOp('replace')
                              ->setPath('transactions/0/amount')
                              ->setValue(json_decode('{
                                "total": "'.$amount->total.'",
                                "currency":"USD",
                                "detail": {
                                  "subtotal": "'.$amount->details->subtotal.'",
                                  "shipping":"'.$shippingRate.'"
                                }
                              }'));


        //Instantiate a new instance of PayPal's Patch Request Class and Update the Transaction with the tax and shipping rate
        $updateRequest = new \PayPal\Api\PatchRequest();
        $updateRequest->setPatches(
          [$transactionUpdate]
        );
        //Attempt Update

        $result = $payment->update($updateRequest, $paypalAPI);

        if ($result) {
          $transID = generateTransactionID();
          $fields = [
            'dateCreated' => strtotime($payment->create_time),
            'transID' => $transID,
            'paymentID' => $payment->id,
            'shipmentID' => $shipment->id
          ];
          $db->insert('transactionLog', $fields);
          Redirect::to('shoppingCartFinalize.php?transID='.$transID);
          exit();
        } else {
          Alert::set([
            'header' => "Uh Oh....Something Went Wrong",
            'message' => "Unable to update transaction. Transaction Cancelled. Please try again.",
            'type' => 'danger',
            'close' => 1
          ]);
          Redirect::to('shoppingCartView.php');
          exit();
        }
      }
```

THe following is the error i get during the call:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http
>   response code 400 when accessing
>   https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-77N347011V970714EKU2D24Q.'
>   in
>   /var/www/html/myla-dev/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:177
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/myla-dev/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(74):
>   PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('[{"op":"replace...') #1
>   /var/www/html/myla-dev/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(103):
>   PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...',
>   'PATCH', '[{"op":"replace...', NULL) #2
>   /var/www/html/myla-dev/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php(474):
>   PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...',
>   'PATCH', '[{"op":"replace...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext),
>   NULL) #3 /var/www/html/myla-dev/apiProcessing.php(146):
>   PayPal\Api\Payment->update(Object(PayPal\Api\ in
>   /var/www/html/myla-dev/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php
>   on line 177

**UPDATE: Thank you for the assistance Thaer. It helped. Now I am getting a separate error. When I attempt to update the payment it is now saying the following:**

> Array (
>       [name] => PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID
>       [message] => This request is invalid due to the current state of the payment
>       [information_link] => https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#PAYMENT_STATE_INVALID
>       [debug_id] => 1b1b9b71e91d8 )

**If you know how to fix this please. I don't know how to change the state so that the payment can be updated.**

If you find an error please let me know. I am so stuck it is not funny.

Dave Douglas

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931011/exception-using-paypal-php-sdk-http-response-code-400)
I think you must try - catch your code to determine error
,regards.

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated my answer with some new info. Can You help?

Answer (score 1):

First, can you confirm if the payment is already executed or not ?

Note that it can only be updated before the execute is done. Once, the payment is executed it is not possible to udpate that. Docs: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#update-a-payment-resource

- You can follow the code shown here to update the Payment here : http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/payments/UpdatePayment.html

And I think your payment has already been executed, and so the `state` would be `complete` and not `created`, which is causing that 400 Exception of invalid state.

Let me know if that makes sense.

To make a change in the payment, you might be able to create a refund, to return the remaining amount.

Alternatively, you could also use authorize or order, to hold the funds first, and then actually charge them later. Kind of how you see it in restaurants, etc, where they hold the fund of your total, but eventually add the tip later, and complete the transaction later.

For more information read here:  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/create-process-order/

Comment: How could the payment be being excuted if i am not called on the execute method. And if i get the details of the payment the state of the payment is still created, otherwise it would be completed and you hypothesis would be correct

Comment: Because your code shows the Payment:get directly, so I assumed, you might be looking at executed payment. IF that is not the case, you could try out the code shown here under `Update payment details` in https://paypal-php-sdk.herokuapp.com/#payments

Comment: That is where I was having the issue. When I would make the call to update it i get that error. I opted to just change e checkout flow and request the user to enter the shipping infomation before call to PayPal and then just call PayPal with everything rather than having to worry about recalling them with an update.

Comment: Asking upfront is something we encourage. That helps user understand what exactly they are being charged, however, all the use cases couldnt fit into that model. If for any reason, you wish to delay that once payment is captured, Order or Capture mentioned about would be a great fit.